# Is it true that Jivan Mukta has capability to nullify his/her karma?

Tags: scripture, karma, advaita, moksha

I am asking the question for all sects that do believe in Jivan Muktha especially Advaita.

According to Advaita, a jivan muktha is also a Brahman.

So, it is clear that she can nullify her karma. Am I correct?

If yes, why do Jivan Muktas generally undergo prarabda instead of nullification?

Answer (score 5):

A jeeva Mukta cannnot nullify his  "**Prarabdh Karma**' if he has any. Which means if there is anything that he is '**supposed to do**' he will have to do that for the sake of divine purpose .

**Bramhasutra says**-

यावदधिकारमवस्थितिराधिकारिकाणाम् ॥ ३२ ॥
yāvadadhikāramavasthitirādhikārikāṇām || 32 ||

**Translation** - Of those who have a mission to fulfill (there is corporeal) existence, so long as the mission is not fulfilled.

Here is commentary given by Adi Shankracharya on the given verse -

> Rishi Apantaratama was born again as Vyasa. Sanatkumara was born as Skanda. So also other Rishis like Vasishtha and Narada were born again. Now these Rishis had attained the knowledge of Brahman, and yet they had to be reborn. **If that is so, what is the utility of such knowledge of Brahman?**—says the opponent. This Sutra refutes it and says that ordinarily a person after attaining Knowledge is not reborn. But the case of those who have a divine mission to fulfil is different. Those perfected sages have one or more births until their mission is fulfilled, after which they are not born again. But then they never come under the sway of ignorance although they may be reborn. **Their case is analogous to that of a Jivanmukta, who even after attaining Knowledge continues his corporeal existence as long as the Prarabdha Karma lasts. The divine mission of these people is comparable to the Prarabdha Karma.**

Comment: Wonderful answer! But a bit sad that he can't nullify his Karma.